# AngularJS : Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] : ng-repeat not working on the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

ng-repeat is not working on the array and i am getting the below error : 
Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

```
<tr>
 <td ng-repeat="(v,version) in versions">
                 <table>
                    <tr>
                       <td ng-hide="true">
                            {{getUniqueOS(AppVersions[version])  }}                                
                        </td> 
                         // ng-repeat is not working on my array : 
                        <td ng-repeat="os in osList track by $index">
                           {{os}}    
                        </td>                     
                    </tr>

                 </table>        
            </td>
</tr>
```

and the below is my controller :

```
   $scope.osList = [];
  $scope.getUniqueOS = function (objVersion) 
  {
        var OsVersions =[];
       OsVersions = objVersion.abc.os;
       for (var curOSVersion in  OsVersions ) 
       { 
        $scope.osList.push(curOSVersion);
       }
      console.log($scope.osList);
   }
```

and the data is getting pushed to my array as below :

```
(33) ["Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10", "Windows 7 Ent 64 Bits SP1", "Mac", "Windows 10"]
```

Actually the array should have only 3 elements : Windows 7,Mac and Windows 10.But it's getting repeated multiple times as above.

Comment: 1. Why do you bind unnecessary function to the view, instead of  binding a scope property? 2. What that function don't return any value? 3. Why don't you use one-time binding to reduce the calculation on every digest cycle?

Comment: @ Alon Eitan : 1. The function is just used to push the data into the object. Hence, it does not return anything and i have called it using ng-hide. I am a beginner in Angular. Please let me know if i am wrong. 2. How can i use one-time binding ?

Comment: I didn't downvote this question BTW, but if this function is not for display purpose so you can call it one from the controller, or using the `ng-init` directive that will ensure it is called once. You use one-time binding like so: `{{ ::getUniqueOS(AppVersions[version]) }}` this make the expression to be evaluated only once, which improves the rendering speed of the view (But you don't need it anyway after reading your last comment - you can call it from the view, or using [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit))

Comment: I forgot to add reference to one-time binding - [Read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: @Alon Eitan : It's working fine now :)  Thanks a lot for additional info on one-time binding.